# Meaning of "get to it" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm puzzled by the use of the phrase "get to something" in a specific context. I know its basic meaning and have searched for information for example [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+to). The sentence I don't understand is:

> Highlight one of your copied groups with a tap. Tap Repeat, and then Grid. **Get to it.** (This is my favorite feature, and I have spent a lot of time on it.)

It's from an [article](https://creativecloud.adobe.com/it/discover/article/jordan-kushins-finds-comfort-in-simple-treasures) published by Adobe on digital art techniques and tools.

Any idea?

Thank you for any insight you might have.

Comment: Thank you both. For some reason that meaning seemed off to me and I thought there was something more to it. Glad it's easier than I thought!

Answer (score 4):

The link you've provided includes a decent definition for the phrase as it's used here:

> **get to something**
>
> 3 Fig. to start on [doing] something; to begin doing something. *I'll get to it as soon as possible. Have you managed to get to my repair job yet? Your complaining is getting to bother me.*

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+to

*Get to it* has essentially the same meaning as the (probably) more common *get to work*.

In this case, the author is inviting the readers to begin using the technique and tools he has just described.  You can find similar invitations in the other steps:

> Tap Radial. *Experiment.*
>
> Tap Repeat, then Mirror. *Reflect ad infinitum.*
>
> Play with the Point Selector. *Get chaotic. Swap colors.*

Answer (score 1):

It implies a sense of urgency to whatever the ‘it’ is i.e ‘Let’s get to it!’ It’s quite American and I don’t think I’ve ever heard an English person say it. It would be seen as sounding a bit silly in the UK.

It’s different than just ‘get to’ which is basically the same of ‘allowed to’ . ‘If you do X you get to do Y’

Comment: Thank you for the subtle insight about the word.